# how to access vue.js api key in laravel application

Tags: laravel, vue.js

hello there i am trying to access my youtube api key located in the .env file from within this code:

```
<template>
   <div class="YoutubeDash__wrapper">
      <video-group :videos="videos"></video-group>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VideoGroup from './VideoGroup.vue';
  import Search from './Search';

  export default {
    components: {
      VideoGroup
    },
    created(){
      Search({
        apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET,
        term: 'laravel repo'
      }, response => this.videos = response);
    },

    data(){
      return {
        videos: null
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

According to the documentation [using env variables with vue.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode). Everything seems to be correct. In my .env file i say: `VUE_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,` what am i missing here ?

I get this error message:

```
app.js:37809 Error: YouTube search would require a key
```

Any tips are welcome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

Answer (score 1):

We need to work with a small amount of information here so I am going to make a few assumptions (based on the tags) mostly that you are using laravel and laravel-mix to compile your resources.

For laravel(-mix) to make your `.env` variables accessible by JS you need to prefix them with `MIX_` i.e. `MIX_VUE_APP_SECRET`. This will make your variable accessible as `process.env.MIX_VUE_APP_SECRET`.

Comment: yes @milo526 i use laravel-mix sorry... i manage it to use a vue.config.js file and import the variable, but i will try your suggestion now.... i prefer to have everything in the .env file....

Comment: nope still not working mmmh my code is like so: Search({
        apiKey: process.env.MIX_VUE_APP_SECRET,
        term: 'laravel repo'
      }, response => this.videos = response);

Comment: You will need to place the `MIX_VUE_APP_SECRET=XXXXXXXXX` in your `.env` file, also be sure to reload your config cache by running `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: did both and still error message Error: YouTube search would require a key
    at module.exports (app.js:47895)
    at VueComponent.created (app.js:47872)
    at callHook (app.js:38989)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (app.js:40698)
    at new VueComponent (app.js:40866)
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (app.js:40378)
    at init (app.js:40199)
    at createComponent (app.js:41676)
    at createElm (app.js:41623)
    at createChildren (app.js:41750)

Comment: running vue in dev mode !?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer excluding laravel-mix from this process.
Usually, in my blade entry-point I use meta tags:

```
<meta name="myVal" content="{{ config('<any-config-key>') }}">
```

`<any-config-key>` can be any laravel configuration key including those taken from `.env`.
Then, in my javascript I do something like:

```
const setVueGlobal = (metaHeaderName, vueGlobalName) => {
    let value = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="' + metaHeaderName + '"]').content;
    if (!value) {
        console.error('some error msg');
        return null;
    }

    Vue.prototype[vueGlobalName] = value;
    return value;
};

setVueGlobal('myVal', '$myVal');
```

Finally, accessing using `this.$myVal`

Comment: good idea @aviram but i am trying to access the laravel .env file to get an api key in a vue context, i don't think its useful to access it in the head tag in my case, but thanks anyway.